# Undelete files on only /home/ disk encryption

Tags: encryption, filesystems, ubuntu

I recently installed xubuntu with /home/ encryption on one of my partitions. I would like to know:

1. Can files deleted normally be recovered?
2. How can I safely overwrite already "insecurely" deleted files in /home/?
   I tried testdisk, what gave me the normal "Directory unmounted to protect your files" message.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Question 2 is unclear. What do you mean with "insecurely" deleted?

Comment: By "insecurely" I mean simply "rm" it from command line. Without overwriting

Comment: So, why would you want to overwrite a deleted file on an encrypted filesystem?

Comment: That's the point, when a file is deleted with "rm", will the "traces" remain there?

Comment: Rather ways, how can I prevent to someone theoretically knowing the encryption key, recovering a file, if it was already deleted with "rm"

Comment: Well, the same techniques apply, and thus, this is a question that depends on the file system used on top of the encrypted volume, not on the encryption. The same "erasing" tools are used, just not on the raw volume, but on the decrypted volume.

Comment: Okay, so, am I taking the same risk leaving the file in the encrypted directory than deleting it with "rm"? I mean, no risk the "traces" going outside of the directory? (ext3)

Comment: Please research how the encryption used works! As soon as you've understood that, you can answer most of your questions yourself; I think this is bound to be more helpful to you than writing a two pages long answer myself that first explains how this /home encryption is done, and how overwriting deletion needs to be done...